# How to convert MySQL timestamp to AWSDateTime with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, aws-amplify

I want to convert MySQL timestamp to AWSDateTime format used in Amplify by PHP.

from
MySQL: `2021-12-16 09:19:05`

to
AWSDateTime: `2021-12-16T09:19:05.000Z`

Comment: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%sZ'), ...`

Answer (score 0):

With [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats), which Laravel uses, this will do.

```php
Carbon::parse('2021-12-16 09:19:05', 'UTC')->toIso8601ZuluString("millisecond");
```

The second parameter of `parse` method is the timezone that `2021-12-16 09:19:05` is expressed in.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can split value to data & time and use spritf:

```
<?php
// split string to data & time array
$date_time = explode(' ', '2021-12-16 09:19:05');

// format new datetime string
$AWSDateTime = sprintf("%sT%s.000Z", $datetime[0], $datetime[1]);

echo $AWSDateTime;
```

[PHP sprintf online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/94e64ee7939bda7735686307418a5bdb/)

Another way (using date_format):

```
$date = date_create('2021-12-16 09:19:05');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z');
```

[PHP date_format](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/c1b42be4482bc90ee99e023d9b749e7f/)